# How to set IIS ApplicationPool "Private Memory Limit" value using PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell, web-administration

I'm using PowerShell for auto-deploying website, and recently found AppPool setting which cannot be set with PS. or at least I did not manage to find out how to do it.

```
$appPool = $serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add($sitename)...
```

I need to set "Private Memory Limit" to some value, but it looks like there is no such property at **ApplicationPool** or **ApplicationPoolRecycling** object.

Does anybode know workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This script uses [Get-Webconfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790561.aspx) and [Set-WebConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807820.aspx) to get the value for private memory for all app pools.  You can set each individually or set the application pool defaults for them to inherit.  I have commented out the line which actually does the set.

```
import-module webadministration

$applicationPoolsPath = "/system.applicationHost/applicationPools"
$applicationPools = Get-WebConfiguration $applicationPoolsPath

foreach ($appPool in $applicationPools.Collection)
{
    $appPoolPath = "$applicationPoolsPath/add[@name='$($appPool.Name)']"
    Get-WebConfiguration "$appPoolPath/recycling/periodicRestart/@privateMemory" 
    # Set-WebConfiguration "$appPoolPath/recycling/periodicRestart/@privateMemory" -Value 1000
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am adding an answer because I was having trouble using the existing.

```
import-module webadministration
$applicationPools = Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools

foreach ($appPool in $applicationPools){
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$appPool.name `
-Name recycling.periodicrestart.privateMemory -Value 7000000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your responses helped me come up with a solution to a problem that I was having with my WSUS servers. I knew that it was the application pool size for the `WsusPool` that was giving me problems so I made the following PS script and applied it to the root `OU` for my `WSUS` servers (I have 3) I was getting a connection error and my option to `Reset Server Node` didn't help. The event viewer had Event IDs 12002, 12012, 12032, 12022, 12042, 12052, and 12072.

```
Set-WebConfiguration "/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add[@name='WsusPool']/recycling/periodicRestart/@privateMemory" -Value 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the `IISAdministration` module:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
$serverManager = Get-IISServerManager
$appPool = $serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add($sitename)
$appPool.Recycling.periodicRestart.privateMemory = $MemoryInKbs
$serverManager.CommitChanges()
```